# Different passwords, same hash check using crypt in php

Tags: php, hash, password-protection

If i use `crypt()` to hash a password:

```
$password = "my_password_12345";
$salt = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
$crypt = crypt($password, $salt);
```

I get something like this

```
echo $crypt; //AG6hHvhjwnqpc
```

So, when I check for the hash I do this and all work fine

```
echo crypt($password, $crypt); //AG6hHvhjwnqpc
```

But why the following happens? I do the same check as above but with a password similar to the previous one and I get the same hash.

```
$password = "my_password_12345_not!";
echo crypt($password, $crypt); //AG6hHvhjwnqpc
```

I would expect a different hash, but instead I'm getting the same

Comment: Use Bcrypt `$2y$` for password hashing, or better yet, `password_hash()`.

Comment: crypt() is hairy and insecure by default; use password_hash() if possible: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: password_hash() is not good for me at the time because of server's php version

Comment: @Matías Then use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, the `crypt` function use only the 8 first characters :

Extract from the [documentation](http://php.net/crypt):

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

Comment: Do you know why this behaviour? Why truncate to 8 characters living a potencial security issue in a given system?

Comment: @Matías The crypt function truncates to the first 8 characters because it used `CRYPT_STD_DES` (depends on your configuration).